# Loading screen stucks in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a simple loading screen between two screens in which I load it until task is not completed but I am stuck only on loading screen.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/loading');
doTask(context);

void doTask(BuildContext context){
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/secondScreen');
}
```

Comment: until task is not completed  ?

Comment: For the sake of simplicity I have converted it just a function but still it doesn't works.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a future builder instead:

```
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: doTask(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Loading();
            }
            return SecondScreen();
          }),
    );
  }

      Future<void> doTask() async {
    // Any future process here
        await Future.delayed(
          Duration(seconds: 3),
        );
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

doTask won't be called, the code does not work after `Navigator.of(context).push()`. Try completing task in loading screen, it is better you do your task in second screen and show loading while task is not complete.

```dart
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<void> doTask() async {
    //Dummy Code, Replace it with your task
    await Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 2),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: doTask(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            return Container(); //Replace it with your widget
          }),
    );
  }
}
```